# Java (Android) - How to get the Location?

Tags: java, android

I used [that solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3145655/2933843) to obtain my location, but I don't know how to get the location outside to use location.getLatitude() & location.getLongitude() later.

Is there any solution to access location from the outside?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't completely under stand your question but if you want to get your gps coordinates you can create a new class GPSTracker.

GPSTracker :

```
public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

private final Context mContext;

// Flag for GPS status
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

// Flag for network status
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

// Flag for GPS status
boolean canGetLocation = false;

Location location; // Location
double latitude; // Latitude
double longitude; // Longitude

// The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

// The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

// Declaring a Location Manager
protected LocationManager locationManager;

public GPSTracker(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
    getLocation();
}

public Location getLocation() {
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // Getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // Getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
            // No network provider is enabled
        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;
            if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                Log.d("Network", "Network");
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
            }
            // If GPS enabled, get latitude/longitude using GPS Services
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                if (location == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return location;
}


/**
 * Stop using GPS listener
 * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app.
 * */
public void stopUsingGPS(){
    if(locationManager != null){
        locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
    }
}


/**
 * Function to get latitude
 * */
public double getLatitude(){
    if(location != null){
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }

    // return latitude
    return latitude;
}


/**
 * Function to get longitude
 * */
public double getLongitude(){
    if(location != null){
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }

    // return longitude
    return longitude;
}

/**
 * Function to check GPS/Wi-Fi enabled
 * @return boolean
 * */
public boolean canGetLocation() {
    return this.canGetLocation;
}


/**
 * Function to show settings alert dialog.
 * On pressing the Settings button it will launch Settings Options.
 * */
public void showSettingsAlert(){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

    // On pressing the Settings button.
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    // On pressing the cancel button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}


@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
}


@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
}


@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
}


@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
}


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}
}
```

And to get the coordinates use this in your activity:

```
GPSTracker gps;
double latitude;
double longitude;

gps = new GPSTracker(your context);
gps.getLocation();
// Check if GPS enabled
if(gps.canGetLocation()) {
    latitude = gps.getLatitude();
    longitude = gps.getLongitude();
}
```

Comment: Did the same thing couple minutes ago, and it works fine. Thank you.