# Finding Location

Tags: android, service, gps, locationlistener

i'm writing a program which i need to get the coordination of my place , latitude and longitude. my problem is i cant get the location and in my Log lat 
and lng are 0 and 0 and i'm trying to run it on a nexus 6P device which is running android M 6.0.1.

here is my `GPSTracker` class

```
package es.euphrat.clover.compass;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;


public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

    private final Context mContext;

    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;
    boolean canGetLocation = false;

    private Location mLocation;

    double latitude;
    double longitude;

    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10;
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1;

    protected LocationManager mLocationManager;

    public GPSTracker(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        getLocation();
    }

    private Location getLocation() {

        try {
            mLocationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            isGPSEnabled = mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            isNetworkEnabled = mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {

            } else {

                this.canGetLocation = true;

                if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    }

                }
                if (mLocationManager != null) {
                    mLocation = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

                    if (mLocation != null) {
                        latitude = mLocation.getLatitude();
                        longitude = mLocation.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
            }

            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                if (mLocation == null) {

                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    }
                    if (mLocationManager != null) {
                        mLocation = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

                        if (mLocation != null) {
                            latitude = mLocation.getLatitude();
                            longitude = mLocation.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return mLocation;
    }

    public void stopUsingGPS() {
        if (mLocationManager != null) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                mLocationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
            }

        }
    }

    public double getLatitude(){
        if (mLocation != null){
            latitude = mLocation.getLatitude();
        }
        return latitude;
    }
    public double getLongitude(){
        if (mLocation != null){
            longitude = mLocation.getLongitude();
        }
        return longitude;
    }


    public boolean canGetLocation(){
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

this is my main method which i'm Logging the result in main activity

```
package es.euphrat.clover.compass.activity;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Locale;

import es.euphrat.clover.compass.GPSTracker;
import es.euphrat.clover.compass.R;
import es.euphrat.clover.compass.adapters.CityAdapter;
import es.euphrat.clover.compass.boxes.CityBox;
import es.euphrat.clover.compass.boxes.CompassAndCityBox;
import es.euphrat.clover.compass.boxes.DateBox;
import es.euphrat.clover.compass.boxes.DayAndNight;
import es.euphrat.clover.compass.database.City;
import es.euphrat.clover.compass.database.DataBaseHelper;
import info.alqiblah.taqwim.MA6;
import uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyConfig;
import uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyContextWrapper;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements      SensorEventListener {

public final String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();

protected DataBaseHelper mDataBaseHelper;
protected CompassAndCityBox mCompassAndCityBox;
protected DateBox mDateBox;
protected CityBox mCityBox;
protected DayAndNight mDayAndNight;
protected SensorManager mSensorManager;
protected LinearLayout myRoot;
protected DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
protected RelativeLayout gpsDrawer;
protected RelativeLayout cityListDrawer;
protected ArrayList<String> mCityNames;
protected ListView cityListView;
protected EditText searchCity;
protected City[] mCities;
private CityAdapter mCityListAdapter;
protected City currentCity;
protected GPSTracker mGPSTracker;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);

    CalligraphyConfig.initDefault(new CalligraphyConfig.Builder()
            .setDefaultFontPath(getTypeface())
            .setFontAttrId(R.attr.fontPath)
            .build());

    myRoot = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_root);
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    gpsDrawer = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.gps_drawer);
    cityListDrawer = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.city_list_drawer);
    cityListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    searchCity = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_city);

    drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);

    MA6.InitPlanetsTerms(this);
    mGPSTracker = new GPSTracker(this);
    mCityNames = new ArrayList<>();
    mDataBaseHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);
    mCityBox = new CityBox(this);
    mDateBox = new DateBox(this);
    mCompassAndCityBox = new CompassAndCityBox(this);
    mDayAndNight = new DayAndNight(this);

    myRoot.addView(mCityBox);
    myRoot.addView(mDateBox);
    myRoot.addView(mCompassAndCityBox);
    myRoot.addView(mDayAndNight);

    searchCityTextView();
    createTheDataBase();


    double a = mGPSTracker.getLatitude();
    if (mGPSTracker.canGetLocation()) {

        Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(mGPSTracker.canGetLocation()));
        Log.d(TAG, a + "," + mGPSTracker.getLongitude());
    }
}




private void createTheDataBase() {
    try {
        mDataBaseHelper.createDataBase();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG , "Cannot Create DataBase", e);
    }
}

private void searchCityTextView() {
    searchCity.clearComposingText();
    searchCity.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            Cursor cursor =     mDataBaseHelper.selectOrSearchAllCities(searchCity.getText().toString());
            updateList(cursor);

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
}

private void updateList(Cursor cursor) {
    mCityNames.clear();

    final int cityName = cursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseHelper.CITY_NAME);
    int timeZone = cursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseHelper.CITY_TIMEZONE);
    int countryName = cursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseHelper.COUNTRY_NAME);
    int lat = cursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseHelper.CITY_LATITUDE);
    int lng = cursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseHelper.CITY_LONGITUDE);

    mCities = new City[cursor.getCount()];
    int c = 0;
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()){

        String city = cursor.getString(cityName);
        String tZone = cursor.getString(timeZone);
        String country = cursor.getString(countryName);
        float latitude = cursor.getFloat(lat);
        float longitude = cursor.getFloat(lng);

        mCities[c] = new City(city,tZone,country,latitude,longitude);
        c++;
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }

    mCityListAdapter = new CityAdapter(this, mCities);
    cityListView.setAdapter(mCityListAdapter);
    cityListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            currentCity = new City(mCities[position]);
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(cityListDrawer);
            mCityBox.setCurrentCityName(currentCity);
            hideKeyboard();
        }
    });
}

private void hideKeyboard() {
    InputMethodManager inputManager =
            (InputMethodManager)
                    getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(),
            InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
}


public void antenaClick(View view) {

    drawerLayout.openDrawer(gpsDrawer);
}

public void pinpointClick (View view){

    drawerLayout.openDrawer(cityListDrawer);
}



@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION),
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);

    mDataBaseHelper.openDataBase();

    Cursor cursor = mDataBaseHelper.selectOrSearchAllCities(searchCity.getText().toString());
    updateList(cursor);

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);

    mDataBaseHelper.close();
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    float degree = Math.round(event.values[0]);
    mCompassAndCityBox.setDegreeFromNorth(degree,currentCity);
}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

}

@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
}

private String getTypeface(){

    if( Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage().toLowerCase().startsWith("en")) return "fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf";

    else return "fonts/IRAN Sans.ttf";
}

}
```

and this is my manifest

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              package="es.euphrat.clover.compass">
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />



        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            >
            <activity android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>

        </manifest>
```

can any one please help me to find a solution for my problem.

Comment: Check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30407229/java-android-how-to-get-the-location/30407410#30407410 it is almost the same code.

Comment: @Maantje hello , its exactly the same code but its not working for me

Comment: Do you have the correct permissions in your manifest and GPS on on your device? The code works i use it in a couple of my apps without any problems.

Comment: @Maantje i think so bro, i putted my manifest here , could you please take a look at it , oh and do you have an android device which runs android M?

Comment: Try and add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />` this line `isNetworkEnabled = mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);` needs that permission

Comment: @Maantje I've added`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`this line in my manifest and cleaned my project and uninstalled it from my phone then reinstalled it still its giving me 0 and 0 for latitude and longitude :(

Comment: There are problems with the "GPSTracker" code. Firstly `getLastKnownLocation()`may often return either `null` or a location that's not up-to-date. Secondly it calls `requestLocationUpdates()` to request location updates but then it doesn't use any of the updates that are delivered in the `onLocationChanged()` callback. Unless you call `stopUsingGPS()` the device keeps draining the battery and providing location updates that are not used for anything. It's sad that such bad example code keeps popping up in people's web searches.

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen any better solution my friend?

Comment: In any case implement the `onLocationChanged()` to receive the new location and assign it to `mLocation` there. If you just need the current location once you can call [LocationManager.requestSingleUpdate()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestSingleUpdate%28java.lang.String,%20android.location.LocationListener,%20android.os.Looper%29) or just keep using the `requestLocationUpdates()` to keep receiving updates.